# MATLAB video only updating for one loop

Tags: matlab, loops, object, video, frame

My code plots a pulse `roundtrips` number of times for `filters` number of filters. I am trying to create a video of this pulse for every round trip such that there are `roundtrips*filters` number of frames in the video. So far, this is what my code looks like:

```
writerObj = VideoWriter('pulses.avi'); % Name it.
writerObj.FrameRate = 60; % How many frames per second.
fid=figure;
hold on

for kk=1:filters
    open(writerObj);

    for ii=1:roundtrips
              %fid=figure;

          pause(0.1);
          figure(fid)
          subplot(2,1,1);plot(TT,abs(U1).^2);xlabel('Time (ps)','fontsize',12);ylabel('Power (W)','fontsize',12);
          title(['roundtrips = ',num2str(ii),'m']);
          subplot(2,1,2);plot(FF,abs(fftshift(ifft((U1)))).^2);xlabel('Freq. (THz)','fontsize',12);ylabel('Spectrum (arb. units)','fontsize',12)


          frame = getframe(gcf); % 'gcf' can handle if you zoom in to take a movie.
          writeVideo(writerObj, frame);
     end
    hold off
    close(writerObj);
end
```

The problem is that it only shows `roundtrips` number of pulses in the video. I tried moving the `open(writerObj)` to before the `kk` loop, but I got an error message. Any ideas?

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: I guess your problem is `open` and `close` are located inside the loop. Did you moved both `open` and `close` outside of the loop?

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `figure(fid)` every time. You can just use `getframe(fid)` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was move the lines `hold off` and `close(writerObj)` to after the kk loop. Easy peesy!